# iPad TableView Design

Tags: tableview

I would like to use the clean and simple type of `UITableView` designs that Apple uses on their iTunes Connect app for iPad.
Looking at the Markets tab.
The top TV uses the 1st row for column names, the following rows hold the data that corresponds with those columns.
When you scroll up the top row (the column labels) stay put as you'd expect, like the way a typical spread sheet is set up.

How is that being accomplished? I cant get that functionality using the available styles.

I'm also interested by the header and surrounding rounded rectangle of the bottom TV, is that accomplished with graphics in a `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sections and rows methods. The sections create your headers that float as you scroll through your table and the rows contain the records that the user can select. There are several different styles. Here is a good [explanation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of tableview styles. If you need to create more complex tables what you need to do is create a [collection](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pvvn1L2aPyA&ei=jcqFUpnFLKuP7Ab1qIGADw&usg=AFQjCNHAl8mr9uGKOQx9ax3yNgAf4GilSQ&sig2=ZeDGUdwkZmYM2pASCDVmJw&bvm=bv.56643336,d.ZGU).
Below is sample are the method used for creating sections and rows.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 10; //you could take the count of records in an NSarray/NSdictionary here instead
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 5; //you could take the count of records in an NSarray/NSdictionary here instead
}
```